# Animated scrolling when intra-page links are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have the following code to get the ID of a `<a href="#ID"> </ a>` and go to their respective div `<div id="" />`:

```
$('a[href=#certificados]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#certificados').offset().top }, 1000);
});

$('a[href=#team]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#team').offset().top }, 1000);
});

$('a[href=#house]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#house').offset().top }, 1000);
});

$('a[href=#contact]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#contact').offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

How could I optimize the code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get the "respective" div in a more general way from the link's `href` attribute:

```
$('a[href=#certificados], a[href=#team], a[href=#house], a[href=#contact]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 1000);
    // this.hash would be equivalent to $(this).attr("href") in your case
});
```

Probably you also can use a much better selector now - maybe selecting those links by a common class.

Comment: Bad thing about this solution is maintaining the list of items and the slower look-up. You would be better off using a common classname.

Comment: @epascarello: That's what I suggested in the last sentence :-)

Comment: Just hoping the OP saw it. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make the code DRYer, you can do

```
['#certificados', '#team', '#house', '#contact'].forEach(function(anchor){
    $("a[href="+anchor+"]").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(anchor).offset().top }, 1000);
    });
})
```

If all internal links are to be handled this way, do

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Why a forEach? jQuery supports multiple elements in a selector!

Comment: @epascarello to not compute n and to be dryer on the a[href=...] thing

Comment: Maybe rename `n` to `anchor` ?, +1

Comment: `this.href` does not work

Comment: `this.href` returns the full URL, You would need to use `this.getAttribute("href")` or `$(this).attr("href");` or hash http://jsfiddle.net/7439C/1/

Comment: @dystroy that bit me in the butt awhile back, will not forget that one. lol

Comment: @epascarello I was bitten too... and I keep forgetting ^^ And I also remember the behavior was different on IE...

Answer (score 3):

You can make an extension, that will let you specify what link scrolls to where, without creating a hard dependancy between the `href` attribute and the target identity:

```
$.fn.scrollTo = function(target){
  return this.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top }, 1000);
  });
};

$('a[href=#certificados]').scrollTo('#certificados');
$('a[href=#team]').scrollTo('#team');
$('a[href=#house]').scrollTo('#house');
$('a[href=#contact]').scrollTo('#contact');
```

Comment: Nice, but this doesn't optimize it at all.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea: Funny that you should single out this answer and point out that it won't optimise the code (and I assume that you only mean optimise for speed, not any other aspect), as neither of the previous answers does that either...

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the anchors, like `scrollable`.

```
$('.scrollable').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

Each is called under the hood, no crazy functions, just KISS.